Selection Area Deforms When Browser Zoom is Applied in Vue App with Panzoom and Vue3-Moveable using HTML canvas
I'm working on a Vue application where I use a canvas to draw pixels, and I enable panning and zooming using the "panzoom" library. I also use "vue3-moveable" to select areas on the canvas. Everything works fine until I apply browser zoom. When the browser zoom is applied, the selection area becomes deformed and does not maintain its proper alignment with the canvas.
<template>
  <div class="vw-100 vh-100 bg-danger">
    <div
      ref="container"
      @mousemove="handleMouseMove"
      class="vw-100 vh-100 position- overflow-hidden d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center"
      style="background-color: yellow"
    >
      <div
        class="m-container position-absolute start-50 top-50 bg-success m-0 p-0"
      >
        <div
          class="target m-0 p-0 position-absolute bg-info"
          ref="target"
          style="width: 1px; height: 1px"
        ></div>
        <Moveable
          className="moveable"
          class="position-absolute"
          v-bind:target="['.target']"
          v-bind:draggable="true"
          v-bind:resizable="true"
          @drag="onDrag"
          @resize="onResize"
          @dragEnd="onDragEnd"
          @resizeEnd="onResizeEnd"
          :throttleResize="1"
          :throttleDrag="1"
          :snappable="true"
          :stopPropagation="true"
          :bounds="config.bounds"
          :origin="true"
          :keepRatio="true"
          :edge="false"
          :zoom="zoom"
        />
      </div>
      <canvas
        ref="canvas"
        style="background-color: red"
        :width="config.width"
        :height="config.height"
      >
      </canvas>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>


<script setup>
import { onBeforeUnmount, onMounted, reactive, ref } from 'vue';
import Moveable from 'vue3-moveable';
import panzoom from 'panzoom';

let canvas = ref(null);
let container = ref(null);
let zoomInstance = ref(null);
let target = ref(null);
let zoom = ref(1);

let config = reactive({
  width: 400,
  height: 300,
  bounds: null,
});

onBeforeUnmount(() => {});

onMounted(() => {
  //document.body.style.zoom = (1 / window.devicePixelRatio);

  // console.log(document.body.style.zoom)

  drawPixels();

  if (canvas.value) {
    zoomInstance.value = panzoom(container.value, {
      zoom: false,
      initialZoom: 1,
      minZoom: 1,
      maxZoom: 700,
      pan: true,
      pinch: false,
      bounds: false,
      boundsPadding: 0,
    });

    zoomInstance.value?.on('zoom', function () {
      zoom.value = 1 / zoomInstance.value.getTransform().scale;
      getBounds();
    });
    zoomInstance.value?.on('pan', function () {
      getBounds();
    });
  }

  getBounds();
});
function getBounds() {
  let canvas_rect = canvas.value.getBoundingClientRect();
  let xCenter = canvas_rect.left + config.width / 2;
  let YCenter = canvas_rect.top + config.height / 2;

  config.bounds = {
    left: canvas_rect.left - xCenter,
    right: xCenter - canvas_rect.left,
    top: canvas_rect.top - YCenter,
    bottom: YCenter - canvas_rect.top,
  };
}

function onDragEnd() {}
function onResizeEnd(e) {
  console.log(e);
}

function onDrag({ transform }) {
  target.value.style.transform = transform;
}
function onResize({ drag, width, height }) {
  target.value.style.width = `${width}px`;
  target.value.style.height = `${height}px`;
  target.value.style.transform = drag.transform;
}

function handleMouseMove(e) {
  const scale = zoomInstance.value.getTransform().scale || 1;
  const rect = canvas.value.getBoundingClientRect();
  const x_inc = config?.width % 2 === 0 ? 0 : 0;
  const y_inc = config?.height % 2 === 0 ? -0 : 0;
  const x = Math.floor((e.clientX - rect.left + 0.01) / scale + x_inc);
  const y = Math.floor((e.clientY - rect.top + 0.01) / scale + y_inc);
  const index = y * config?.width + x;
}

function drawPixels() {
  //set array data
  const arr = new Uint8ClampedArray(4 * config.width * config.height);
  // Fill the array with the same RGBA values
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 4) {
    let hex = getRandomHexColor();

    let color = hexToRgb(hex);

    arr[i + 0] = color.r; // R value
    arr[i + 1] = color.g; // G value
    arr[i + 2] = color.b; // B value
    arr[i + 3] = 255; // A value

    // Red rectangle
  }
  // Initialize a new ImageData object
  let imageData = new ImageData(arr, config.width, config.height);

  // Draw image data to the canvas
  canvas.value.getContext('2d').putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
}
function getRandomHexColor() {
  // Generate a random number between 0 and 16777215 (0xFFFFFF)
  const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215);
  // Convert the random number to a hex string and pad with leading zeros if necessary
  const hexColor = `#${randomNumber.toString(16).padStart(6, '0')}`;
  return hexColor;
}
function hexToRgb(hex) {
  var result = /^#?([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})$/i.exec(hex);
  return result
    ? {
        r: parseInt(result[1], 16),
        g: parseInt(result[2], 16),
        b: parseInt(result[3], 16),
      }
    : null;
}
</script>

<style scoped>
canvas {
  image-rendering: pixelated;
}
</style>

The issue occurs specifically when the browser zoom is applied, causing the selection area to not scale properly with the canvas, leading to deformation. I'm looking for advice on how to maintain the correct scaling and positioning of the selection area when the browser zoom is applied.
direct link for code :
https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-8xxxbs?file=src%2FApp.vue
I tried using the following function to handle the browser zoom issue:
function toggleZoomScreen() {
    document.body.style.zoom = (1 / window.devicePixelRatio);
}

However, this makes the screen small and does not utilize the full screen properly. I also added the following meta tag to the HTML, but it didn't resolve the issue:
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
nothing change
The selection area must function correctly across all browser sizes and different device pixel ratios.
